# Авторизация на Стиме

Tags: python, cookie, steam-web-api

Хочу сделать себе "бота" для сайта http://steamcommunity.com/

Сделал авторизацию. При переходе на другую страницу, я уже не авторизован. Я так понимаю нужно как то  куки передавать при запросе? В чем может быть дело, и как это решать.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import urllib
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import bs4
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import re
import sys
import os

donotcache = 146845136
password = 'i4Ry4siI'
username = 'chita'
rsatimestamp = '64000000'
phone_cod = input('Введите код с мобильного:  ')


url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/'            
dann = {                            'donotcache':donotcache,
                                'password':password,
                                'username':username,
                                'twofactorcode':phone_cod,
                                'emailaut':'',
                                'loginfriendlyname':'',
                                'captchagid':'-1',
                                'captcha_text':'',
                                'emailsteamid':'',
                                'rsatimestamp':rsatimestamp,
                                'remember_login':'true'
                                }
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url,dann)                     #>тправка пост запроса)
print(r.url)
result = r.text
print(r.text)

reg = re.search('false',r.text)
print(reg)

if reg == None:
   print('GOOD!!!')
else:
   print('BAD!!')
```

---

Comment: У стима вроде есть API?

Comment: В данном случае есть,но не уверен что в данной ситуации он сможет мне помочь.
Речь идет не только о Steam, а о сайтах в целом

Comment: Очень рекомендую использовать для подобных целей Selenium